# After installing nvidia drivers, computer freezes after locking, can't even get to tty

Tags: debian, nvidia, xfce

Since I've installed the `nvidia-drivers` package, when I lock the screen by running `xflock4` it goes to a blank screen with a flashing cursor in the upper left hand corner.

The system becomes completely unresponsive and I can't even switch to the terminal.

I am running Debian Buster.

I switched to the newest kernel image. (4.13.0-1-amd64 at the time of writing)

Running `nvidia-detect` told me to install the `nvidia-driver` package. I have the latest version installed (384.98-3)

My graphics card is GeForce GTX 1060

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to run `nvidia-xconfig`.

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-xconfig
nvidia-xconfig
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the Info. I'm on Debian Testing (Buster) too and I had the same problem. After locking the screen with `xflock4`, `tty7` was not accessible anymore. `nvidia-xconfig` fixed it for me as well. Now there is a xorg file under `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.

I found something similiar [here](https://github.com/the-cavalry/light-locker/issues/77).